# How to map query result to List<Object> in R2DBC?

Tags: oracle, spring-data, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am trying to migrate my JDBC based application to R2DBC, however I struggle with List based objects. How can I map the result from query to "List" field?

I was using ResultSetExtractor, but in R2DBC there is no option like that so I try to do it manually. I use DatabaseClient with manual mapping, however this mapping does not work with List type fields.

```
public class Employee {
private Long id;
private String name;
private String surname;
private List\<Account\> accounts;
}

public class Account {
private String employeeId;
private String accountNumber;
}

public class EmployeeRepository {
private final DatabaseClient databaseClient;

    public static final BiFunction<Row, RowMetadata, Employee> EMPLOYEE_MAPPER =
            (row, rowMetadata) -> Employee.builder()
                    .id(row.get("id", String.class))
                    .name(row.get("name", String.class))
                    .surname(row.get("surname", String.class))
                    .accounts(List.of(new Account((row.get("employeeId"), (row.get("accountNumber")))))
                    .build();
    
    public Flux<Employee> findCardByPan(Long id) {
        return databaseClient.sql("SELECT id, name, surname, a.accountNumber FROM employee e JOIN account a on e.id = a.employeeId WHERE e.id = :id")
                .bind("id", id)
                .map(EMPLOYEE_MAPPER)
                .all();
    }

}
```

Current response model:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Test User",
        "surname": "Test User",
        "accounts": [
            {
                "employeeId": "1",
                "accountNumber": "98034"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Test User",
        "surname": "Test User",
        "accounts": [
            {
                "employeeId": "1",
                "accountNumber": "12456"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected response model:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Test User",
        "surname": "Test User",
        "accounts": [
            {
                "employeeId": "1",
                "accountNumber": "98034"
            },
            {
                "employeeId": "1",
                "accountNumber": "12456"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You can use `collectList` like this `var data = findCardByPan(4L).collectToList()` this will give you `Mono<List<User>>` then you can use regular map function to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way i can suggest but not optional in my opinion.

You can access the values by using `row.get(int index, Class<T> type);` but that leads to many inspections about the `row.size`. Also when the `get` method returns `null` `for` should break and not forget to match the correct index with the correct field you want to fill.

I am trying also to find out another way to use it because it is very error prone but for now this is what i have ended up with.